# Align image in footer with text in footer

Tags: graphics, alignment, footer

I need to add the logo of my university (as a .png) in the footer of my thesis, but it is not on the same level as the text in the footer. How can I make sure that the university logo is aligned with the bottom of the text (my thesis title and the page number)?

I used the following source code to make this footer:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=30mm, right=30mm, bottom=30mm, top=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\newcommand{\mytitle}{Thesis title}
\cfoot{\mytitle}
\lfoot{\includegraphics[width=2.29cm,height=0.6cm]{Logo.png}} 

\begin{document}
The content of my thesis goes here
\end{document}
```

This is the result of the code above. I would like the image of the university logo to be aligned with the rest of the footer. Because as you can see on the image, the bottom of the logo is higher than the bottom of the text.

Thank you for helping me!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  How can I post a Minimal Working Example? I am new to Stack exchange and latex :)

Comment: You can edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I cannot compile your code, I am not sure that this is what you want, but you can try to replace

```
\lfoot{\includegraphics[width=2.29cm,height=0.6cm]{img/Logo.png}}
```

with

```
\lfoot{\vtop{\vskip-.5ex\hbox{\includegraphics[width=2.29cm]{img/Logo.png}}}}
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: I would have used `\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{...}`, but the important thing is that it looks good.